# Printing within dynamic sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following bit in a stored proc -

```
DECLARE @SQL varchar(5000)

SET @SQL = 'select count(*) as "Total Population" from [dbo].[Final_Results]'

EXEC (@SQL)
```

I have gone through some contents online but I am still confused over the pros/cons on using Set Versus Select here. So can anyone help me with it?

Also I would like to return the result of " EXEC (@SQL)" in a print statement. Need some directions on that too.

Thanks.

Comment: Set or Select doesn't matter when you are setting a variable to a literal string.

Comment: There really isn't a difference between `SET` and `SELECT` in this setting.  I personally use `SET` as it's more clear as to what I'm doing.

Comment: @Siyual/ @Dave.Gugg - Also I would like to return the result of " EXEC (@SQL)" in a print statement. Cna you please help on that.

Comment: Just to add something to what Dave and Siyual said, if you use `SET` it's clear to the reader of your code that you are making a trivialn assignation, and he doesn't have to look for more complex stuff in that line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will print your result instead of selecting in the grid view:

```
DECLARE @SQL varchar(5000)

SET @SQL = 'declare @count bigint 
            select @count = count(*) from [dbo].[Final_Results] 
            print ''Count of Total Result Population = '' + cast(@count as varchar(20))'

EXEC (@SQL)
```

Comment: Thanks. I want to print something like "Count of Total Result Population = x". How can I get the same?

Comment: Updated per your new spec

Comment: @0nir - you should update the question title to reflect the new question - it's about printing within dynamic sql, no longer about set vs select.

Comment: Please don't advocate [varchar without length. It's so sloppy and potentially problematic](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx).

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Thank you, I've updated.